# Google Analytics discrepancy - excluding IP address

Tags: google-analytics, looker-studio

Friday the 22nd of november we've gotten over the course of 2 hours two different conversion amounts in Google Data studio (=> pulled data from Google Analytics).

At 15.00 pm we hit 22 conversions. Some time later at 17.00 pm we hit 9 conversions.

At 14.45pm the website (https://zaza.rocks) went down. So not willing to corrupt our data a test IP address was excluded from Google Analytics.

With that being said it seems strange that the conversion amount changed during that time window due to an exclusion of 1 IP Address. So I am wondering:

1. Can an IP exclusion change previously acquired conversions in a short time window?
2. Perhaps Google Data studio pulled wrong data due to a bug from 14pm to 17pm
3. Another reason?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Google Analytics the data can be considered stable after 48 hours (within that time they can be reworked).
If you have converted on the same day that you applied the IP filter (which excludes the network from which you made the conversion) you must consider, i.e., that after midnight Analytics reprocesses the data of the day and therefore applies the filter to the whole day just ended (even if you added the filter only in the afternoon).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
Does Google Analytics have multiple moments during a day where it reprocesses data? For instance at 12pm, 6pm and 9pm?

Comment: There is no a specific rule, however the data can be considered reliable in max 4h for GA360 and 24-48h for Google Analytics standard.